# c++ winsock2 bad pointers breakpoint triggered

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, winsock2

I have a server and a client. I am using winsock2. The client sends 4 bytes:

```
char *ack = new char[4];
sprintf( ack, "%d", counter );
sendto( clientSocket, ack, 4, 0, ( struct sockaddr* )&remote, sizeof( remote ) );
```

and the server receives these 4 bytes:

```
char* acks = new char[4];
if( ( bytes = recvfrom( serverSocket, acks, 4, 0, ( struct sockaddr* )&remote, &remote_size ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    cout << "socket error = " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    break;
}
if( bytes > 0 ) {
    sscanf( acks, "%d", &i );
}
```

I am getting this error and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
>Critical error detected c0000374
>
>server.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

I know there is a problem with the pointer and the memory allocation. But my c++ skills are basic.

Comment: If you know for sure that the char is 5 in size.. why not just do `char acks[5] = {0};` Also, can you show the declarations of "remote" and "remove_size"?

Comment: The size is actually 4. I tried different things and I forgot to bring back the code to the right form. The declaration of the array pointer should have been 

`char* acks = new char[4];`

The other declarations are:

`SOCKADDR_IN remote;

int remote_size = sizeof( remote );`
And thank you for helping.

Comment: I actually edited my original post and fixed the length of the char array pointer

Comment: I just want to add that the error occurs in the sscanf line. If I comment that line the error occurrs in the recvfrom line. The only common array pointer in these two lines is acks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## String formatting overflow

The most pressing issue is that you are using sprintf and sscanf. Avoid using sprintf and sscanf - they make it far too easy to accidentally create the type of bug you're seeing here, which is buffer overflow (on both your client and your server).

Consider what happens on your client when your 'counter' value is 1729. Your code will run

```
sprintf(ack, "%d", 1729);
```

The C-style-string representation of 1729 is *five bytes long* - one byte each for the char values `'1'`, `'7'`, `'2'`, `'9'`, and `'\0'`. But your ack buffer is only 4 bytes long! Now you've written that last zero byte into some chunk of memory you never allocated. In C/C++, this is **undefined behavior**, which means your program might crash, or it might not, and if it doesn't crash, it might end up subtly wrong later, or it might work perfectly well, or it might work most of the time except it breaks on Tuesdays.

It's not a good place to be.

You might be wondering, "if this is so awful, why didn't the `sprintf` just return an error or something I called it with a buffer that was too small?" The answer<sup>1</sup> is that `sprintf` can't make that check because it doesn't give you any way to tell it how big `ack` actually is. When your code here is calling `sprintf`, *you* know that ack is 4 bytes long (since you just created it), but all sprintf sees is a pointer to some memory, somewhere - you haven't told it a length, so it just has to blindly hope the chunk of memory you give it is big enough.

Blindly hoping is a pretty bad way to write software.

There's a few alternatives you could consider here.

1. If you are actually just trying to send an int across the wire, there's not really any need to stringify the int at all - just send it in its native format by passing `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&counter)` as your buffer to sendto<sup>2</sup> with sizeof(counter) as the corresponding buffer length. Use a similar construction in recvfrom on the other end. Note that this will break if your sender and your receiver have different underlying representations of ints (for example, if they use different endiannesses), but since you're talking about Winsock here I'm assuming you're assuming both ends are reasonably recent versions of Windows where that won't be a problem.
2. If you really do need to stringify the content first, use size-cognizant string conversion functions, like [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) (which is implicitly size-cognizant because it deals in std::string instead of raw char* buffers) or [_snprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx)/[_snscanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dktz45bk.aspx) (which explicitly take in buffer length parameters, but are Microsoft-specific).

## Recvfrom access violation

The overflow in sscanf/sprintf doesn't necessarily explain this, however:

> I just want to add that the error occurs in the sscanf line. **If I comment that line the error occurrs in the recvfrom line.**

One possible explanation for this could be not providing adequate space for the remote address, though so long as your `remote_size` is a correct reflection of your `remote`, I'd expect this to cause `recvfrom` to return an error<sup>3</sup>, not crash. Another possibility is passing bad memory/handles (for example, if you've set up the `new` operator to not throw on failure, or if your socket initialization failed and you didn't bail out). It's impossible to say exactly without seeing the code initializing all the variables in play, and ideally the actual error you get in that scenario.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even though sprintf can't catch this, static analysis tools (like those included in Visual Studio 2012/2013) are very capable of catching this particular bug. If you run the posted code through the default Visual Studio 2012 Code Analyzer, it will complain with:

> error C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe

<sup>2</sup> Some people prefer `static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&counter))` to `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&counter)`. Both work, it's essentially a coding convention choice.

<sup>3</sup> For example, if you were initializing `remote` as a `SOCKADDR_IN` instead of a `SOCKADDR_STORAGE`, you might encounter such an error if you happened to receive from an IPv6 address. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842041/2825668) goes through some of the relevant gory details.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation. Now it makes sense. I actually thought that the int bytes are stored as bytes. So if an integer is never more than 32 bits = 4 bytes, I thought the length will never overflow. I increased the length of the char array pointer to 8 and it is ok now. It may overflow for large integers but my program won't use such big integers. Now it works fine. I am in a rush to hand this project so I don't have time to make deeper changes.
On a side note, there is a reason why this site is named stack overflow :-)

Comment: An int (on Windows) is indeed 4 bytes long, but the *string representation of an int* can be much longer (a byte per digit plus a null terminator).