# What is the correct way to determine which sockaddr variant to use?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I want to know the proper way to determine which sockaddr variant to use.

From [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html):

```
if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
    addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    ipver = "IPv4";
} else { // IPv6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
    addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
    ipver = "IPv6";
}
```

Here he is checking if the address family is `AF_INET` and using `sockaddr_in` if it is.  If it isn't he is using `sockaddr_in6`.  Isn't that unsafe?  What if it was some other address family that is not IPv6?

Is there a sanctioned, standard way of determining which structure maps to the corresponding address family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to be safe, you could use an `else if` for AF_INET6 and a final `else` to fail with unsupported address family. I would avoid attempting to have support for other families unless you have actual requirements to support them. Following [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), it's unwise to code to a spec if you have no plans to support or test it.

```
if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
    addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    ipver = "IPv4";
} else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) { // IPv6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
    addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
    ipver = "IPv6";
} else {
    // UNSUPPORTED! FAIL! FAIL!
}
```

Comment: In my case I need to pass through calls even with unfamiliar address families.  In those cases I would just ignore the data and copy it as a void pointer.  Why it isn't a void pointer in the first place confuses me but I guess it is just legacy code.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using `sockaddr_storage`. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835322/api-using-sockaddr-storage) why