# How exactly does sockaddr_storage work?

Tags: c, sockets

I just started to get into socket programming. I don't understand how by just declaring sockaddr_storage and then make a socket listen(), all the incoming connections just automatically get stored in sockaddr_storage. What if you declare 5 sockaddr_storage?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8842041/841108) to a similar question

Comment: "I don't understand how by just declaring sockaddr_storage and then make a socket listen(), all the incoming connections just automatically get stored in sockaddr_storage." - ***that's because they don't***.

Comment: You might want to have a closer look at the arguments to [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/accept.html).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That's exactly where I should have looked into at first. Now I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How exactly does sockaddr_storage work?

`sockaddr_storage` is a type that's big enough to hold a socket address for any supported protocol (`sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, `sockaddr_un` for UNIX domains, `sockaddr_bth` for Bluetooth, etc).

> I don't understand how by just declaring sockaddr_storage and then make a socket listen(), all the incoming connections just automatically get stored in sockaddr_storage.

That's because they don't.
You have to pass a `sockaddr_storage` to a function that fills it with a socket address, like `accept()`, `getsockname()`, `getpeername()`  etc.

> What if you declare 5 sockaddr_storage?

Then you have 5 variables of type `sockaddr_storage`. Nothing special happens. It's the same as if you asked "what if you declare 5 ints?" You still have to populate them somehow.

Comment: Be careful with the limitations: Because `sockaddr_storage` needs to be [*large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html). Which is e.g. why `sockaddr_un` limits maximum path length.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to reed [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) and [Beej's Guide to Unix Interprocess Communication](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/) it's really worth it.