# how to get ipv4 and ipv6 packets using the same socket in Windows, it was working on linux

Tags: c++, sockets

```
int m_nSocket6;
sockaddr_in6 m_address_6;

/*created the socket*/

m_nSocket6 = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

int ret;
/* Set socket buffer size */

    int buffer_size;

   ret = setsockopt(m_nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*) &buffer_size, sizeof(buffer_size));

/* Set socket timeout */

    int timeout = m_nTimeout;
    ret = setsockopt(m_nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*) &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

/*Multicast*/

int yes = m_nMulticast; //1 = enabled
    ret = setsockopt(m_nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&yes, sizeof(yes));

/*bind*/

     memset((char *)&abc, 0, sizeof(m_address6));
     m_address6.ss_family = AF_UNSPEC;
     m_address6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
     m_address_6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
     m_address6.sin6_port = htons((u_short)m_nPort);
     ret = bind(m_nSocket6, (struct sockaddr*) &abc, sizeof(abc));

/*receiving the packets*/

recvfrom(m_nSocket, m_sBuffer, UPD_DATAGRAM_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &m_address, &server_length);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835322/api-using-sockaddr-storage) and [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/Winsock2example7.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with *both* IPv4 and IPv6 traffic with a single socket, you must create a **dual-stack socket**, which is an IPv6 socket that has the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option disabled.

Refer to MSDN documentation for more details:

[Dual-Stack Sockets for IPv6 Winsock Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665.aspx)

> In order to support both IPv4 and IPv6 on Windows XP with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and on Windows Server 2003, an application has to create two sockets, one socket for use with IPv4 and one socket for use with IPv6. These two sockets must be handled separately by the application.
>
> **Windows Vista and later offer the ability to create a single IPv6 socket which can handle both IPv6 and IPv4 traffic**. For example, a TCP listening socket for IPv6 is created, put into dual stack mode, and bound to port 5001. This dual-stack socket can accept connections from IPv6 TCP clients connecting to port 5001 and from IPv4 TCP clients connecting to port 5001. This feature allows for greatly simplified application design and reduces the resource overhead required of posting operations on two separate sockets.